# Referencing a anchor tag in ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am getting an `Array` of items with `jinja2` from a database in an `<a>` tag, item[0] represent an id while item[1] is an attribute (e.g name).
 I would like to make reference to the id in my `ajax` call so if I click anything in my `anchortag` it makes reference to the id, now once I click anything in my `anchortag`, everything just runs with no reference to id

**HTML**

```
{% for item in people %}
   <a id="foo" class="foo">{{item[1]}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**JAVASCRIPT/AJAX**

```
{% for item in people %}

$(".foo").click(function(evt) {
$.ajax({
 url: "/~s6/cgi-bin/people.py",
 async: true,
 type: "post",
 datatype:"json",
 data: {'peopleid': {{item[0]}}},
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result)
        //console.log(result.peopleinfo.surname)
       // console.log(result.peopleinfo.othernames)
        console.log(result.familyinfos)

         html = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>" + "<tr><th>Old Name</th><td>" + result.peopleinfo.surname  + "</td></tr>"' + "<table>"

$('#infoTab').html(html)

 $("#placenameModal").modal("show");
      }

  });


  });
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass the ID of the anchor tag clicked to the ajax request? If so you can use `$(this)` to access the link that was clicked and grab the ID like so: `$(this).attr('id')`.

Also by the looks of your code you are adding multiple click events when you only need one.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem you're trying to solve is.  What do you mean by "makes reference to the id"?   You already appear to be passing the ID to the AJAX call (as the 'peopleid' param), is there something in the response that isn't working?  (Possibly you just need `<a id="{{item[0]}}" class="foo">{{item[1]}}</a>` instead of `id="foo"`?)

Comment: Oh, wait.  You're assigning click handlers inside a loop; `$(".foo").click()` is getting assigned to the same elements for every item  in your `people` array, so clicking a single link will fire *all* of them.  Use `{{item[0]}}` as both the link ID (as in my previous comment) and when you're assigning the click handler (instead of `$('.foo').click()` use `$('#{{item[0]}}')`.)

Comment: @DanielBeck yes!!!!!! thank you. that worked

Comment: @lloyd I would look at one of the two answers below to avoid multiple event handlers.

Comment: @dahliacreative okay thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

**HTML**

```
{% for item in people %}
   <a id="{{item[0]}}" class="foo">{{item[1]}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).on('click', '.foo', handleClick)
function handleClick(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/~s6/cgi-bin/people.py",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      peopleid: $(this).attr('id')
    },
    success: handleModal
  })
}
function handleModal(response) {
  // Do stuff here with your response
}
```

Comment: Also should be `$('#{{item[0]}}').on('click'...)`, probably

Comment: Only if it's in a loop, but I wouldn't recommend adding all those event handlers. You only need one attached to the class `foo` then you can just grab the ID from the element that was clicked.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't notice you were reading the ID from the clicked element, that works.  But they do need to move this code outside their loop, or they'll end up with multiple event handlers attached to each link

Comment: Yeah, I'm suggesting keeping the JS out of the loop. It's pointless attaching multiple events when only one is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the information you need in `data` attributes.

```html
{% for item in people %}
    <a id="foo" class="foo" data-people-id="{{item[1]}}" data-people-name="{{item[1]}}">{{item[1]}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Then just get the data you need when an anchor is clicked.

```js
function anchorClickHandler(evt) {
    var anchor = $(this)[0];                    // get the anchor DOM element, unwrapped from jQuery
    var peopleId = anchor.dataset.peopleId;     // get the peopleId from the data attribute
    var peopleName = anchor.dataset.peopleName; // you can do the same with the name, if you want
    $.ajax({
        url: "/~s6/cgi-bin/people.py",
        async: true,
        type: "post",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {
            'peopleid': peopleId,   // pass in the peopleId from the specific anchor that was clicked.
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result)
            // console.log(result.peopleinfo.surname)
            // console.log(result.peopleinfo.othernames)
            console.log(result.familyinfos)

            html = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">' +
                        '<tr>' +
                            '<th>Old Name</th>' +
                            '<td>' + result.peopleinfo.surname + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                    '</table>'

            $('#infoTab').html(html)
            $("#placenameModal").modal("show");
        }

    });
}

$(".foo").on('click', anchorClickHandler);
```

It's also a decent idea to define your handlers outside of the actual assignment.
If you were to define your handlers in a loop, then a copy of your handler would get bound instead of the handler itself.

While you won't notice a difference on smaller pages, it does not scale well at all and can affect performance on larger pages.